# Travis CI: compilar un proyecto maven multimodular con dos versiones de Java

Tags: java, maven, java-11, travis-ci

Tengo un proyecto maven con la siguiente estructura:

regextester

- automatonosgi
- client
- client-idea
- client-netbeans
- client-web
- generex
- regextester-js

de ellos necesito compilar `client-idea` con Java 17 (le llamare a esta fase `compile1`) y los demás con Java 8 (le llamare a esta fase `compile`).

En mi local lo logro teniendo los dos JDKs.
Compilo todo con Java 8 con un `maven install`
cuando falla compilo `client-idea` con Java 17

El principal problema esta en que cuando lo mando a un pipeline idealmente no debe de fallar para no dar resultados equivocados

### Intentos

primeramente intente con `jdk_switcher` pero parece que no esta presente según [este incidente](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8681), asi que estoy intentando con jobs y stages

#### .travis.yml

```
os: linux
dist: xenial
language: java
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2

services:
  - xvfb

addons:
  chrome: stable
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq update || echo no sudo apt-get
  - sudo apt-get install -y libgnome2-0
  - sudo apt-get install -y libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 || echo no sudo apt-get
  - wget https://github.com/sormuras/bach/raw/releases/11/install-jdk.sh
  - chmod +x $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/install-jdk.sh
  # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &

stages:
  - compile
  - compile1

jobs:
  include:
    - name: job1
      stage: compile
      jdk:
        - openjdk11
      install:
        - mvn install -pl org.javapro:regextester-js,org.javapro:automatonosgi,org.javapro:generex,org.javapro:client,org.javapro:regextester-web,org.javapro:regextester-nb -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -ntp
      script:
        - mvn test -pl org.javapro:regextester-js,org.javapro:automatonosgi,org.javapro:generex,org.javapro:client,org.javapro:regextester-web,org.javapro:regextester-nb org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report -B -ntp
      after_success:
        - mvn coveralls:report -B
      workspaces:
        create:
          name: ws1
          paths:
            - $HOME/.m2
    - name: job2
      stage: compile1
      jdk:
        - openjdk17
      depends_on: job1
      workspaces:
        use: ws1
      install:
        - mvn install -pl org.javapro:regextester-idea -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -ntp
      script:
        - mvn test -pl org.javapro:regextester-idea org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report -B -ntp
```

### errores

Cuando llega al trabajo 2 (`job2`) obtengo el siguiente error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project regextester-idea: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.javapro:regextester-idea:jar:1.0.4: Failed to collect dependencies at org.javapro:client:jar:1.0.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.javapro:client:jar:1.0.4: Could not find artifact org.javapro:regextester-pom:pom:1.0.4 in google-maven-central (https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/) -> [Help 1]

esto a pesar de que todo indica que se comparte el cache de workspace (`ws1`) correctamente ya que salen estas líneas

> found workspace

> 2.36s$ tar -xPzf ${CASHER_DIR}/ws1-fetch.tgz